# Linking jQuery to an html document

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to learn how to make websites and I've gone through to tutorials on http://www.codecademy.com/learn for html/css and jQuery but I can not figure out how to link the jQuery document for so I can use jQuery. A quick google search told me to download jQuery but not only do I not completely know what that does, I don't know how to use it.

Here's what I have from the information I've gathered as far as linking the two documents..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="New.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script> type="text/javascript" src="New.js"></script>
</head>
```

The file I want the Jquery in being New.js and it contains:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Comment: you have a typo here  after the first script dont close the tag. <script type="text/javascript" src="New.js"></script>

Comment: Either I've fixed the issue and there was no change or I messed up more/again.

Comment: Are you using the correct path to your .js files?

Comment: Does it need to a literal or relative path?

Comment: it needs a relative path

Comment: Should be the correct relative path. But it's just sitting on my desktop right now. #Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have a small typo - last `<script>` in `<head>` should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="New.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome works perfect. I've been trying to do this for a while now and you come in and fix it in 5 secs.. Thanks. :P

Comment: It's always the small ones that get you :)